# Trouble changing background of input textbox

Tags: javascript, html, background-color, rgb

I'm trying to create a textbox where if you submit the correct answer, the textbox's background turns green, and red for the incorrect answer. However, nothing seems to happen for both options.

```js
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  //Stuff
  let input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
  let answer = input.value.toLowerCase().trim();

  if (input.timeoutId) {
    clearTimeout(input.timeoutId);
  }

  // Compare with the correct answer
  if (answer === 'palm tree' || answer === 'a palm tree') {
    input.style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'; // Green for correct answer
    input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      input.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    input.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'; // Red for incorrect answer
    input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
      input.style.backgroundColor = '';
    }, 2000);
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<h3>
  What tree can you hold in your hand?
</h3>
<form>
  <input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="q" placeholder="Answer" type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's all of the code, if you need it. For some reason it's working on here, but not in github.dev. Here's the mini trivia page: https://forharrisonbaby-turbo-umbrella-w6xrjxgqrqvfgwrg-8080.app.github.dev/index.html?q=hello. The previous code snippet is at the bottom.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: #fff;
                color: #212529;
                font-size: 1rem;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.5;
                margin: 0;
                text-align: left;
            }

            .container {
                margin-left: auto;
                margin-right: auto;
                padding-left: 15px;
                padding-right: 15px;
            }
            b1{
                padding-left:20px;
                padding-right: 100px;
                color: #ff0000;
                transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            }

            b2{
                padding-right: 130px;
                color: #00ff00;
                transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            }

            b3{
                padding-right: 180px;
                color: #ff0000;
                transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            }

            b4{
                padding-left: 500x;
                color: #ff0000;
                transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out
            }


            .hidden{
                visibility: hidden;
            }
            .header {
                background-color: #477bff;
                color: #fff;
                margin-bottom: 2rem;
                padding: 2rem 1rem;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .section {
                padding: 0.5rem 2rem 1rem 2rem;
            }

            .section:hover {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                color: #477bff;
                transition: color 10s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
            }

            h1 {
                font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
                font-size: 48px;
            }

            h2 {
                margin-top: 0;
                margin-bottom: 0;
                padding-top: 0;
                padding-bottom: 0;
            }

            button, input[type="submit"] {
                background-color: #d9edff;
                border: 1px solid transparent;
                border-radius: 0.25rem;
                font-size: 0.95rem;
                font-weight: 400;
                line-height: 1.5;
                padding: 0.375rem 0.75rem;
                text-align: center;
                transition: color 0.15s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out, border-color 0.15s ease-in-out, box-shadow 0.15s ease-in-out;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            input[type="text"] {
                line-height: 1.8;
                width: 25%;
            }

            input[type="text"]:hover {
                background-color: #f5f5f5;
                transition: color 2s ease-in-out, background-color 0.15s ease-in-out;
            }
        </style>
        
        <title>Trivia!</title>
        <script>
            // TODO: Add code to check answers to questions
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
                function check(id, message){
                    let button = document.querySelector(`#${id}`);
                    if (id === 'id2'){
                        button.style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'; //green
                        //button timing
                        message.style.visibility = 'visible';
                        if (button.timeoutId) {
                            clearTimeout(button.timeoutId);
                        }
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            button.style.backgroundColor = '';
                            message.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        }, 1000);
                    }else{
                        button.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'; //red
                        message.style.visibility = 'visible';
                        if (button.timeoutId) {
                            clearTimeout(button.timeoutId);
                        }
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            button.style.backgroundColor = '';
                            message.style.visibility = 'hidden';
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            var message1 = document.querySelector('b1'); //Incorrect
            var message2 = document.querySelector('b2'); //Correct
            var message3 = document.querySelector('b3'); //Incorrect
            var message4 = document.querySelector('b4'); //Incorrect
            document.querySelector('#id1').addEventListener('click', function(){
                check('id1', message1);
            });
            document.querySelector('#id2').addEventListener('click', function(){
                check('id2', message2);
            });
            document.querySelector('#id3').addEventListener('click', function(){
                check('id3', message3);
            });
            document.querySelector('#id4').addEventListener('click', function(){
                check('id4', message4);
            })
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">
            <h1>Trivia!</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section">
                <h2> Part 1: Multiple Choice </h2>
                <hr>
                <!-- TODO: Add multiple choice question here -->
                <h3>
                    What does the Mushroom tell the other Mushroom when they're the only Mushrooms in their world?
                </h3>
                <button id="id1"> I'm a Fun Guy!</button>
                <button id="id2">There's 2 mushroom?</button>
                <button id="id3"> Let me trufle over to you.</button>
                <button id="id4"> "Sigh". Lets wallop on the pizza-ria...</button>
                <div>
                    <b1 class="hidden">Incorrect</b1>
                    <b2 class="hidden">Correct</b2>
                    <b3 class="hidden">Incorrect</b3>
                    <b4 class="hidden">Incorrect</b4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Part 2: Free Response</h2>
                <hr>
                <!-- TODO: Add free response question here -->
            <h3>
                What tree can you hold in your hand?
            </h3>
            <form>
                <input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="q" placeholder="Answer" type="text">
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <script>
                document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                    //Stuff
                    let input = document.querySelector('input[name="q"]');
                    let answer = input.value.toLowerCase().trim();

                    if (input.timeoutId) {
                        clearTimeout(input.timeoutId);
                    }

                    // Compare with the correct answer
                    if (answer === 'palm tree' || answer === 'a palm tree') {
                        input.style.backgroundColor = '#00ff00'; // Green for correct answer
                        input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                            input.style.backgroundColor = '';
                        }, 2000);
                    } else {
                        input.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000'; // Red for incorrect answer
                        input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
                            input.style.backgroundColor = '';
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                });
            </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work as expected for me.. When I type in 'palm tree' the background color of the input turns green for 2 seconds then goes back to default. When I type anything other than 'palm tree' the background turns red for 2 seconds then goes back to default.

Comment: Please review your question. If you click the "Run code snippet" button on your question, it does work.

Comment: It's pretty strange. Here it works, but when I try to run it in github.dev, nothing happens. Heres the mini trivia page. https://forharrisonbaby-turbo-umbrella-w6xrjxgqrqvfgwrg-8080.app.github.dev/index.html?q=hello

Comment: @Harrisino The link seems to be broken (with status `404`); please check the access right.

Comment: @hokwanhung  Nevermind. The website is run in github, so if I don't pay attention to it for a long time, it just turns off. I've included all the code including the css, so if you run the bottom portion now, it should be exactly the same as to what I'm experiencing.

Comment: @Harrisino Thank you for the code; it is interesting that GitHub.dev has such behaviours, similar to Jupyter Notebook on `Python`. You could possibly answer your own question.

Comment: @hokwanhung Yeah. I just made it so that you could run the bottom portion here, and it gives the results I want. It's probably a problem on their end. I'm just gonna say that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the build-in form validation. Set the `required` and `pattern` attributes on the input element. If the value is invalid the callback for the invalid event will be called. If the value is valid the form will submit and the submit callback will be called.

```js
document.forms.form01.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let input = event.target.q;

  input.classList.add('valid');

  input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    input.classList.remove('valid');
  }, 2000);
});

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('invalid', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  let input = event.target;

  input.classList.add('invalid');

  input.timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
    input.classList.remove('invalid');
  }, 2000);
}, true);
```

```css
.invalid {
  background-color: red;
}

.valid {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>
  What tree can you hold in your hand?
</h3>
<form name="form01">
  <input autocomplete="off" autofocus name="q" placeholder="Answer"
  type="text" pattern="(a )?palm tree" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```